# passenger: pass request to rack application if no file found

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, rack

If it were `php`, it'd be something along the lines:

```
server {
    server_name   ...;
    root   /path/to/root/1;
    location / {
        try_files   $uri   @root2;
    }
    location @root2 {
        root   /path/to/root/1;
        try_files   $uri   /index.php?$args;
    }
    location = /index.php {
        include   fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   php;
    }
}
```

In other words, the point is to separate public files into several directories. Is there a way to do this with `passenger` + `nginx` + `sinatra` (to be precise)?

**UPD** Basic `nginx`/`passenger` setup:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /home/yuri/example.com/public;
    passenger_enabled   on;
}
```

For more information see [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
server {

  [...]

  root /path/to/public/folder;

  [...]

  location / {
    # Serve static files or forward to passenger
    try_files $uri $uri.html @passenger
  }

  location @passenger {
    passenger_enabled on;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Um, `passenger` doesn't listen to ports, `nginx` connects to `passenger` using unix sockets. I see 5 of them now. But I doubt they can be used this way. Take a look at basic `nginx`/`passenger` setup, I added to my question. Besides, using `if` is a [bad practice](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) and to be avoided if possible.

Comment: Well, it appears it works. I wonder how come I didn't check out this way to set it up... Or could it be that I made a mistake and ended up thinking it's no good... Anyway, thanks.

Comment: As to serving `index.html`, `nginx` has got `index` directive with default value of `index.html`. So `$uri/index.html` in your `try_files` is superfluous.